# How can I check if numbers are consecutive primes?

Tags: java

The input line contains three positive integers: `r`, `s`, and `a`, where `(2 <= r < s < a)`.  It is guaranteed that `r` is prime.

It should print `YES`, if `s` is the next prime number after `r` and `a` is the next prime number after `s`; otherwise, it should print `NO`.

Currently, I have the following `isPrime()` method:

```
boolean isPrime(int n)  {
    //check if n is a multiple of 2
    if (n%2==0) 
        return false;
    //if not, then just check the odds
    for(int i=3;i*i<=n;i+=2) {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried as for the consecutive requirement? We're not doing your homework if you haven't tried that.

Comment: That is piece I am confused about.. And need help on. Any pointers will be appreciated

Comment: Are they all prime? Are any numbers in between them prime?

Comment: Also, your isPrime method says 2 is composite...

Comment: Trivial (suboptimal solution): 1. are all three prime.  2. loop across r-s and s-a, checking for primes there.  If the first succeeds (yes three primes), and the second two fail (no, no other primes), then you have success.  Otherwise, fail.

Comment: I need to return YES if they are all prime..NO otherwise

Comment: I think these must be sufficient enough http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475996/given-prime-number-n-compute-the-next-prime http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468412/finding-a-prime-number-after-a-given-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public int nextPrime(int start){
    int next = start+1;

    while(!isPrime(next)){
        next++;
    }

    return next;
}

public void arePrimeSequence(int r, int s, int a){
    int firstPrime = nextPrime(r);
    int secondPrime = nextPrime(firstPrime);

    if(s == firstPrime && a == secondPrime){
        System.out.println("YES");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("NO");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some improvement can be made in the code to determine next prime. Instead of incrementing by 1 you can increment the number by 2. As first number is guaranteed as prime and if it is not 2 then increment  by 2.

public int nextPrime(int start){

```
if (start==2) return 3;
int next = start+2;

while(!isPrime(next)){
    next+=2;
}

return next;
```

}